# How can I sort a linked list in C?

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I need to be able to either sort or insert entries to a linked list in alphabetical order. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: Smells like homework?

Comment: dirkgently's only contribution came from his NOSE when it should have been from his MIND.

Answer (score 6):

[mergesort](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html) is fine for the sorting (the insertion in the already-sorted list is even simpler of course, if that's what you're asking about).

Comment: the mergesort implementation you link to isn't very efficient and will most likely be outperformed by a recursive version; better yet, use the stack-based approach and get entirely rid of unnecessary list traversals (code example: http://pastebin.com/f44b2e39b )

Answer (score 2):

You can use the qsort() function in libc. Essentially, you'll create an array of pointers to your nodes, and write a node comparison function... You'd then call qsort() and finally re-create your list in the new order specified by qsort().

Answer (score 1):

One can implement a version of `quicksort` for a single-linked list, but normally this is only interesting as a puzzle, since `mergesort` is much easier to implement and works equally well (or better) for sorting linked lists.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting is easy, just step through the list till you find the right place, put your new node there (the previous node now links to the new node, the new node to the node the previous node previously pointed to).

If you already have an unsorted list, there is no efficient way to sort it within the list, which means you have to create a second collection and sort there, e.g. using a binary tree or an array and quicksort.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your list already sorted and want to insert a *whole lot of items*, it may be better to insert them at the beginning and sort afterwards; if you want to insert *only a few items* it may be better to keep the list sorted.

**My reasoning:**

- Insertion at the beginning is O(1);
- Insertion keeping the list sorted is O(N);
- Sorting the list is O(N log N) *(at best)*

So, the *whole lot of items* above is, therefore, **log N items or more** and the *only a few items* is less than **log N items**.

Comment: With linked list, it's better to sort new elements, then go through the original already sorted list once and insert new elements to correct positions on the way.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start with sorting by hand, and get an idea how you would sort, then, see if you can get that written in a psuedo-code. From there it would be easy to convert that to a program.

To get help with homework it helps if you explain how you want to do the sort, show some code that isn't working, and explain what it should do, and what it is doing, and then you may find help more forthcoming.

Since you are using a linked list, if you can do a binary tree then a binary sort, esp if you can sort while inserting, would be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, try to keep the linked list sorted while inserting new items.

However, this question was answered, one way or the other, on the following StackOverflow posts:

[Inserting a node into a linked list in constant-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294234/inserting-a-node-into-a-linked-list-in-constant-time)

[How do you insert into a sorted linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320460/how-do-you-insert-into-a-sorted-linked-list)

[Sort a singly Linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842407/sort-a-singly-linked-list)

[What’s the fastest algorithm for sorting a linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525117/whats-the-fastest-algorithm-for-sorting-a-linked-list)

[Sorting a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768095/sorting-a-linked-list)

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you should reimplement yourself (unless this is a homework question...). I use glib, which implements a linked list and sorted insert so you don't have to. Here's the [appropriate glib documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.20/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html#g-list-insert-sorted-with-data).

Answer (score 0):

If your list is doubly-linked, you can turn it into a binary tree and then back into a linked list again.

This requires no auxilliary storage.

[Sorting a linked list by turning it into a binary tree](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/articles/sorting-a-linked-list-by-turning-it-into-a-binary-tree.html)